# Error when creating policy in Oracle Label Security

Tags: oracle, security

I ran into a "failure to create trigger" error when creating policy in Oracle Label Security. Here's my code:

```
-- step3: Creating a Labeling Function for a Policy
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION project2.gen_users_label
      (Id varchar2,
        Security_level varchar2
        )
  Return LBACSYS.LBAC_LABEL
as
  i_label varchar2(80);
Begin
  /************* Determine Security Level *************/
  i_label := Security_level;

  /************* Determine Compartment *************/
  i_label := i_label||':'||Id;  -- user_id

  return TO_LBAC_DATA_LABEL('users_read_pol',i_label);
End;

-- step4: apply the policy to a table or entire schema
BEGIN
  SA_POLICY_ADMIN.APPLY_TABLE_POLICY (
  policy_name    => 'users_read_pol',
  schema_name    => 'project2', 
  table_name     => 'users',
  table_options  => 'READ_CONTROL',
  label_function => 'project2.gen_users_label(:new.id,:new.security_level)',
  predicate      => NULL);
END;
```

Here's the error message:

```
Error starting at line : 27 in command -
BEGIN
 SA_POLICY_ADMIN.APPLY_TABLE_POLICY (
  policy_name    => 'users_read_pol',
  schema_name    => 'project2', 
  table_name     => 'users',
  table_options  => 'READ_CONTROL',
  label_function => 'project2.gen_users_label(:new.id,:new.security_level)',
  predicate      => NULL);
END;
Error report -
ORA-12433: create trigger failed, policy not applied
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.LBAC_POLICY_ADMIN_INT", line 436
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.LBAC_POLICY_ADMIN_INT", line 418
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.LBAC_POLICY_ADMIN_INT", line 346
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.LBAC_POLICY_ADMIN_INT", line 412
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.LBAC_POLICY_ADMIN", line 84
ORA-06512: at line 2
12433. 00000 -  "create trigger failed, policy not applied"
*Cause:    The policy could not be applied due to errors during the
           creation of a DML trigger.
*Action:   Correct the SQL syntax of the label function specification.
```

But I couldn't figure out what's wrong with the label function specification. Here's the documentation I referred to: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/olsag/implementing-policy-enforcement-options-and-labeling-functions.html#GUID-0A6AD167-42C2-4F13-958A-F3D73F0B798D